# Command Line through C# -- commands not executing

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, command-line, amazon-s3

I'm using C# and AWS's CLI for S3.  I seem to be having the same or a similar issue in two different places.  In the first, I'm trying to execute multiple commands with the same process.  The first command is to set the environment variables for the access key and secret key for AWS S3.  The next two commands are just a simple `ls` to see what's in the bucket already and a sync to update its contents.  If I take the commands to set the environment variables out, it works fine (because I'm already configured on the machine I'm working on), but since I need this to work on other machines, the environment variables need to be set.  However, if they are, the following commands do not execute.  Here's code for this:

```
String commands = @"set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=keykeykey set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=secretsecretsecret";
commands += @" & aws s3 ls s3://bucket";
commands += @" & aws s3 sync C:\test s3://bucket/kaaaaay";
```

The issue reappears in a different method.  There, I need to get the value from a registry key.  I know the command is correct, because it works just fine in a command line window.  Here's code for that:

```
String commands = @"Reg.exe QUERY HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\GIJOE\HASAKEY";
```

Any help would be much appreciated, because I'm stumped.

Comment: Why are you using a command line utility to access the registry when [C# has these function built-in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: C# has them built in? I did not know that.  Going to look into it, thank you!

Comment: Also consider that, you may not have access to the registry on a remote system for security reasons.

Comment: I should have access, but I'll keep that in mind.